# add a lot of rows with jsreport-core

Tags: jsreport

relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003222/how-to-append-files-with-jsreport-core/68015642#68015642).

I have a lot of rows to add to the report. the report can be in excel or pdf.
and I want to add it in bulks.
how it can be achieved?

Comment: What recipes do you want to use? Why do you want to use bulks instead of normal iteration? Please share some examples..

Comment: I want to use chrome-pdf and html to excel.
for example, if I have 1 million rows that I need to add to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [chrome-pdf](https://jsreport.net/learn/chrome-pdf) recipe doesn't support bulks. The html generation is typically fast enough and chrome uses multiple threads to render big tables and there is no space for further optimization.

The [html-to-xlsx](https://jsreport.net/learn/html-to-xlsx) recipe includes optimization techniques for big tables. The main point is to use the `htmlToXlsxEachRows` which splits rows and runs the conversion in bulks.

```js
<table>
    {{#htmlToXlsxEachRows people}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{address}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/htmlToXlsxEachRows}}
</table>
```

See the [performance](https://jsreport.net/learn/html-to-xlsx#performance) section for the further information.